# In the software Maxima, how to get the k-th element in a list

Tags: maxima-software

I looked up the manual and only find functions
first([1,2,3])
second([1,2,3])
third([1,2,3])
...

how to get an element by an index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PART function, e.g. PART([1,2,3],2) = 2.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

S:[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h];

S[3]; $\Rightarrow$ c

S[7]; $\Rightarrow$ g

Comment: Note that it works also with constant lists: $[a,b,c][2]$ evaluates to $[b]$